# can pthread_cond_signal make more than one thread to wake up?

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, condition-variable

I'm studying on condition variables of Pthread. When I'm reading the explanation of `pthread_cond_signal`, I see the following.

> The `pthread_cond_signal()` function shall unblock **at least one** of
>   the
>          threads that are blocked on the specified condition variable cond (if
>          any threads are blocked on `cond`).

Till now I knew `pthread_cond_signal()` would make only one thread to wake up at a time. But, the quoted explanation says *at least one*. What does it mean? Can it make more than one thread wake up? If yes, why is there `pthread_cond_broadcast()`?

---

En passant, I wish the following code taken from [UNIX Systems Programming book of Robbins](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/unixtm-systems-programming/0130424110/) is also related to my question. Is there any reason the author's `pthread_cond_broadcast()` usage instead of `pthread_cond_signal()` in *waitbarrier* function? *As a minor point, why is **`!berror`** checking needed too as a part of the predicate?*  When I try both of them by changing, I cannot see any difference.

```
/*

 The program implements a thread-safe barrier by using condition variables. The limit
 variable specifies how many threads must arrive at the barrier (execute the
 waitbarrier)  before the threads are released from the barrier.
 The count variable specifies how many threads are currently waiting at the barrier.
 Both variables are declared with the static attribute to force access through
 initbarrier and waitbarrier. If successful, the initbarrier and waitbarrier
 functions return 0. If unsuccessful, these functions return a nonzero error code.

 */

#include <errno.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>

static pthread_cond_t bcond = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;
static pthread_mutex_t bmutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
static int count = 0;
static int limit = 0;

int initbarrier(int n) {              /* initialize the barrier to be size n */
    int error;

    if (error = pthread_mutex_lock(&bmutex))        /* couldn't lock, give up */
        return error;
    if (limit != 0) {                 /* barrier can only be initialized once */
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&bmutex);
        return EINVAL;
    }
    limit = n;
    return pthread_mutex_unlock(&bmutex);
}

int waitbarrier(void) {    /* wait at the barrier until all n threads arrive */
    int berror = 0;
    int error;

    if (error = pthread_mutex_lock(&bmutex))        /* couldn't lock, give up */
        return error;
    if (limit <=  0) {                       /* make sure barrier initialized */
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&bmutex);
        return EINVAL;
    }
    count++;
    while ((count < limit) && !berror)
        berror =  pthread_cond_wait(&bcond, &bmutex);
    if (!berror) {
        fprintf(stderr,"soner %d\n",
                (int)pthread_self());
        berror = pthread_cond_broadcast(&bcond);           /* wake up everyone */
        }
    error = pthread_mutex_unlock(&bmutex);
    if (berror)
        return berror;
    return error;
}

/* ARGSUSED */
static void *printthread(void *arg) {
    fprintf(stderr,"This is the first print of thread %d\n",
            (int)pthread_self());
    waitbarrier();
    fprintf(stderr,"This is the second print of thread %d\n",
            (int)pthread_self());
    return NULL;
}

int main(void) {
    pthread_t t0,t1,t2;

    if (initbarrier(3)) {
        fprintf(stderr,"Error initilizing barrier\n");
        return 1;
    }
    if (pthread_create(&t0,NULL,printthread,NULL))
        fprintf(stderr,"Error creating thread 0.\n");
    if (pthread_create(&t1,NULL,printthread,NULL))
        fprintf(stderr,"Error creating thread 1.\n");
    if (pthread_create(&t2,NULL,printthread,NULL))
        fprintf(stderr,"Error creating thread 2.\n");
    if (pthread_join(t0,NULL))
        fprintf(stderr,"Error joining thread 0.\n");
    if (pthread_join(t1,NULL))
        fprintf(stderr,"Error joining thread 1.\n");
    if (pthread_join(t2,NULL))
        fprintf(stderr,"Error joining thread 2.\n");
    fprintf(stderr,"All threads complete.\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I would guess that the function might generate spurious wake-ups but does not guarantee to wake them all like broadcast does.

Answer (score 2):

Due to [spurious wake-ups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spurious_wakeup) `pthread_cond_signal` could wake up more than one thread.

Look for word "spurious" in [pthread_cond_wait.c](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=nptl/pthread_cond_wait.c;hb=c57afec0a9b318bb691e0f5fa4e9681cf30df7a4#l108) from glibc.

---

In `waitbarrier` it must wake up all threads when they all have arrived to that point, hence it uses `pthread_cond_broadcast`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer sir. What about the second one with the code part?

Comment: @snr Added a note about `waitbarrier` for you.

Comment: Thanks but seemingly _pthread_cond_signal_ does give same output as well. By signaling one-by-one with _pthread_cond_signal_ doesn't make any sense w.r.t. _pthread_cond_broadcast_. Does it? That's what I don't understand.

Comment: @snr `waitbarrier` must wake up *all* waiting threads at the same time, this is why it uses `pthread_cond_broadcast`.

Answer (score 0):

> Can [`pthread_cond_signal()`] make more than one thread wake up?

That's not guaranteed.  On some operating system, on some hardware platform, under some circumstances it *could* wake more than one thread. It is *allowed* to wake more than one thread because that gives the implementer more freedom to make it work in the most efficient way possible for any given hardware and OS.

It *must* wake at least one waiting thread, because otherwise, what would be the point of calling it?

But, if your applicaton needs a signal that is guaranteed to wake all of the waiting threads, then that is what `pthread_cond_broadcast()` is for.

---

Making efficient use of a multi-processor system is hard.  [https://www.e-reading.club/bookreader.php/134637/Herlihy,*Shavit*-_The_art_of_multiprocessor_programming.pdf](https://www.e-reading.club/bookreader.php/134637/Herlihy,_Shavit_-_The_art_of_multiprocessor_programming.pdf)

Most programming language and library standards allow similar freedoms in the behavior of multi-threaded programs, for the same reason: To allow programs to achieve high performance on a variety of different platforms.